# Angular ng-show is not executing with ng-message tag

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. 
I want to display an  ng-message after the user submit the form. However , the message is shown when the form is rendered. It seem like the ng-show is not evaluating.

I printed the field in the expression and it is false when I open the form. Also, I change it to ng-hide but I have the same issue.

Can you please have a look ..

```
<div class="small-12">
   <label>first name
<span class="field-error"> *</span>
</label>
<input name="firstName" 
  type="text" 
  maxlength="25" 
  ng-disabled="isSubmitting" required 
  ng-model="candidate.firstName" 
  ng-class="{error:isFormSubmitted && contactForm.firstName.$error.required}" />

<div ng-messages="forms.contactForm.firstName.$error" 
    class="errorFormLabel" role='alert'>
   <div ng-message="required" 
    ng-show="isFormSubmitted">This is a required field {{isFormSubmitted}}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try moving the `ng-show="isFormSubmitted"` onto the `ng-messages` instead of the ng-message element.

Comment: Thanks.. it works after moving it to the ng-messages element.. So, it in not possible to have the ng-show/hide element together with ng-message?  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about `ng-messages` as a `switch` clause, you can nest the /`ng-show`/`ng-hide` inside `ng-message` directive but not use them together

For example:

```
<div ng-messages="forms.contactForm.firstName.$error" 
    class="errorFormLabel" role='alert'>
   <div ng-message="required">
      <span ng-show="isFormSubmitted">This is a required field {{isFormSubmitted}}</span>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want an extra element: `<span>`, try `ng-if`, basically `ng-if` has the priority higher than any other angularjs directive and it will force the `ng-message` directive to be removed from the DOM tree if the expression is not positive.

```
<div ng-message="required" 
    ng-if="isFormSubmitted">This is a required field {{isFormSubmitted}}
  </div>
```